# How to write control style looks like the SketchFlow Sample?

Tags: windows-phone-7, styles

Recently i find the SketchFlow Sample For WPF in blend 4 by accident. I think its very beautiful. so decide to write an WP7 APP With cartoon Appearance, its controls'style looks likes the sketch styles the picture below which is a blend WPF sketckFlow sample. I just have the idea, i don't konw how to start it.

Here is the picture:

[image: WPF SketchFlowStyle]

Comment: FYI: An official SketchFlow template for Windows Phone 7 wsa announced at MIX earlier this year and should be released soon :)

Comment: Note that you can overwrite the default look and feel of all UI controls by overwriting it's style. Check this tutorial: http://wpftutorial.net/Styles.html (this is for WPF, but also applies to WP7)